# How to link a target which might be a shared library when installing a library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, shared-libraries

I have a library that can be build as shared or static and uses another library that is already on the system and can be either shared or static too. The former is a C++ wrapper for the latter, which is a C library

What would the correct `target_link_libraries` call be?

If I do `target_link_libraries(cpplib PUBLIC clib)` then I'm also propagating the include directories of `clib` to consumers of `cpplib` but those should only use the interface provided by the C++ library which has no mention of the clib in its headers.

If I do `target_link_libraries(cpplib PRIVATE clib)` then the include path of consumers is clearer, but when I now do the export-install-install_exports dance of installing a CMake project with its config file and `*targets.cmake` then I have a problem: If both libraries are SHARED then the installed targets of cpplib have no mention of clib and linking against that consequently fails with `libc.so, needed by libcpp.so, not found` and many undefined references.

Both libraries use targets and especially under Windows there is no way to find whether clib is shared or not.

What is the idiomatic way?

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(cpplib)

find_package(clib REQUIRED)
add_library(cpplib SHARED cpplib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cpplib PRIVATE clib::clib)

target_include_directories(cpplib PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/cpplib>)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
set(PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cpplibConfig.cmake")
configure_package_config_file("Config.cmake.in" ${PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE} INSTALL_DESTINATION "lib/cmake")

install(
  TARGETS cpplib 
  EXPORT cpplibTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib 
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin 
)
install(FILES cpplib.h DESTINATION include/cpplib)
install(FILES ${PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE} DESTINATION "share/cpplib")
install(EXPORT cpplibTargets NAMESPACE "cpplib::" DESTINATION "share/cpplib")
```

> Config.cmake.in

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

find_package(BZip2 REQUIRED)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/@PROJECT_NAME@Targets.cmake")
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

> "user" project CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(user)

find_package(cpplib REQUIRED)
add_executable(user main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(user cpplib::cpplib)
```

Edit: As I found it strange, that it works, when I add the executable in the same CMakeLists as the library (so not using the installed version) I dug deeper: I just noticed that CMake clears the rpath on installing:

```
-- Installing: /tmp/install/lib/cpplib.so
-- Set runtime path of "/tmp/install/lib/cpplib.so" to ""
```

Found this while comparing the output of `ldd` of the installed library and the one in the build tree where the latter is able to resolve the clib. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe "resolving dependencies"? I mean the idiomatic expression.

Comment: The error "libc.so, needed by libcpp.so, not found" is a pure **RPATH problem**. Exporting the library is completely **irrelevant**. If you want us to help you with that problem, then you need to provide more code (as [mcve]).

Comment: Ok, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path where clib was installed does solve this. However I though that this was not required for linking but only for running. Still don't fully understand RPATH :/ I added the CMake part of the MWE but it is mostly boilerplate. So I think my question boils down to "Do I really have to modify my LD_LIBRARY_PATH although CMake is able to find the clib? Can't CMake pass the information it has to the linker?" Edit: Just noticed something, updated question...